# in presto, how to use max_by twice with two conditions on the same filed?

Tags: presto, maxby

I want to use max_by(event_id, date_created) twice:
once when date_created<= first_upgrade_date one once when date_created<= prediction_point
is there a way to do that in one query instead of two (in each one using different condition in where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [filtered aggregations](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation). Example:

```
SELECT
  max_by(event_id, date_created) FILTER (WHERE date_created <= first_upgrade_date),
  max_by(event_id, date_created) FILTER (WHERE date_created <= prediction_point)
FROM ...
```